# How to use SUM and GROUP BY to SUM the row and all?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do i get the sum of a row with the `GROUP BY` and also form all the rows without using `WITH ROLLUP`

The ERROR i get is Unknown column 'x' in 'field list'

Example

```
SELECT SUM(orderValue) as x GROUP BY day;
```

But that will only giv me the orderValue for each day, but i want to sum all the order as if i was not using GROUP BY. I know i can use ROLLUP but i need it in the SELECT.

Exmaple:

```
SELECT SUM(orderValue) as x, SUM(x) as total GROUP BY day;

ID  orderValue  day
--  ----------  ---
1   400         2015-01-01
2   800         2015-01-01
3   300         2015-01-01
4   400         2015-01-01
5   600         2015-01-01
6   500         2015-01-01
7   400         2015-01-02
8   800         2015-01-02
9   300         2015-01-02
10  400         2015-01-02
11  600         2015-01-02
12  500         2015-01-02

x       total
3000    6000
3000    6000
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected o/p

Comment: These are just examples of data / sql. What I want to do in the end, among other things, is to calculate the average for each month. And there are several things I do GROUP BY. Eg if the order is made on a mobile or not. So then I have summation of mobile / desktop per day and summation of the two combined.

Comment: So if this code was posible that would solve every problem i have whit this sql query :D
SELECT SUM(orderValue) as x, SUM(x) as total GROUP BY day;

Comment: Show data across multiple years and months (10 rows is enuf) and show `desired results`

Comment: Unknown column 'x' in 'field list' is the ERROR i get.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using cross join with subquery to get the total sum from same table

```
SELECT SUM(orderValue) as x, 
t.total 
FROM table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(orderValue) total FROM table ) t
GROUP BY day;
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91767/2)

Comment: I know that metod to, but i did not want to use that. The SQL i have now is like 20 rows of code, so to add 60 more lines for each sum of stuff seems quite horrible... :/

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery

```
SELECT SUM(orderValue) as x, (SELECT SUM(orderValue) FROM table) as y from table GROUP BY day;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROLLUP` in `SELECT` statements:

```
SELECT day, SUM(orderValue) as x 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY day
WITH ROLLUP;
```

This will return something like

```
day, x
--------
day1,30
day2,50
null,80
```

Comment: the OP did specify without using ROLLUP though

Comment: Well, if you can use it in the sql like sum(WITH ROLLUP /orderValue ) to get a value of it then it would be great :D

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table mySales;

create table mySales
( id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  orderValue int not null,
  theDate date
);

insert mySales (orderValue,theDate) values (100,'2014-01-02'),(600,'2015-01-02'),(9,'2014-07-01'),(1400,'2014-07-02');
insert mySales (orderValue,theDate) values (87,'2014-11-02'),(999,'2015-11-30'),(18,'2014-07-01'),(800,'2013-07-02');
insert mySales (orderValue,theDate) values (11,'2014-1-20'),(9,'2015-11-04'),(1,'2014-07-08'),(6,'2013-05-02');
insert mySales (orderValue,theDate) values (100,'2014-01-02'),(600,'2015-01-02'),(9,'2014-07-01'),(1400,'2014-07-02');
insert mySales (orderValue,theDate) values (87,'2014-11-02'),(999,'2015-11-30'),(18,'2014-07-01'),(800,'2013-07-02');
insert mySales (orderValue,theDate) values (11,'2014-1-20'),(9,'2015-11-04'),(1,'2014-07-08'),(6,'2013-05-02');

select theDate,
sum(orderValue) as dateTotal,
( select sum(orderValue) from mySales
) as grandTotal
from mySales
group by theDate
order by theDate;

theDate, dateTotal, grandTotal
2013-05-02, 12, 8080
2013-07-02, 1600, 8080
2014-01-02, 200, 8080
2014-01-20, 22, 8080
2014-07-01, 54, 8080
2014-07-02, 2800, 8080
2014-07-08, 2, 8080
2014-11-02, 174, 8080
2015-01-02, 1200, 8080
2015-11-04, 18, 8080
2015-11-30, 1998, 8080


select sum(orderValue) from mySales;
8080
```